# Gamma Function with Square

Tags: statistics, factorial, gamma-function

For $\theta$ = 2

$\Gamma$($\theta) ^2$ = [(2-1)!]$^2$ = 1

or

$\Gamma$($\theta) ^2$ = (2$^2$-1)! = 3

Which one is correct?

Comment: The square is outside the parentheses, it applies to the entire function, not the argument.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!,$ and since $\Gamma(\theta)^2 = [\Gamma(\theta)]^2,$ then when $\theta=2,$ we have

$$\Gamma(2)^2 =[(2-1)!]^2=1.$$